# Can I make sshd forward connections to another port for a specific user?

Tags: ssh

We have a macOS based server used for GIT, currently running gitolite, and users SSH to it like ssh git@servername:reponame.

Now we want to switch to running gitlab, in a docker container. Since port 22 is already used by the server, and we need to make it possible to SSH to the gitlab server, ideally on the same port, we are looking for a proper solution for that.

Is it possible to make a rule in sshd, saying something like:

**If connecting user is "git", then forward this to localhost:2222, to make it transparent to any clients?**

Comment: If you use IPv6 the docker container will have a different IP address than the host. No need for port-forwarding at all in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this. We have a "virtual" IP (alias) for the gitlab domain. On the node the container is running on we disable SSHd listening on this virtual IP and then forward 22 to the container. The virtual IP also is handy in case of failover, just attach to a differen node and spin up the container (all data is bindmount lustre).

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. The username in `ssh` protocol is send later int he protocol so there is no way to transparently forward the connection to different port/server so late during the connection.

Running different service on the same server, you will have to use different URI for git, such as `ssh://git@server:2222/path/to/repo.git`.

Comment: That's also my first idea, but i wanted to avoid asking all developers to change the GIT URLs.... 

I'm not an SSH expert, I just hoped that the proxy-approach used with HTTP could be adopted.

Would it be possible to let the GIT user hit a special shell makes an agent-forward ssh connection to another port on localhost?

Comment: It can work with `ForceCommand` though not sure how great idea is that.